# How do I make Trace32 path working for all other users?

Tags: directory, configuration-files, trace32, lauterbach

The configuration file with named `config.t32` under installation of `Trace32` has a static directory default as `SYS=C:\T32`.

When other user runs this file in their system it doesn't runs because they have installed `Trace32` **in different location**.

How can I fix this and make this path work for all users.

Comment: By the way: You should have an empty line before the line RCL=NETASSIST

Comment: In addition to this question, sometimes if local user is changed, in this case as well the Trace32 gives odd errors about temp file premission denied, this is also because config.t32 contains TMP variable path of user who installed Trace, to avoid this comment TMP variable in config.t32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Holger's answer,

I have a huge development team, and to sneak into every setup or to change the path all the time is not possible with common SCM and multiple Test Benches, hence to make more standard tool chain environment, here is something I did.

1. We have defined an environment Variable which has a users string to be defined into Developers PC / on Test Bench.

e.g. `Project_BuildSupport="C:\Tools" (user can defined any path of his choice)`

2. Enter the Environment Variable defined in above step into config.t32 wherever installed.

e.g.

```
SYS=${Project_BuildSupport}\T32-R.2020.09 ;ENV Variable 

HELP=${Project_BuildSupport}\T32-R.2020.09\pdf ;For help
```

In this way all the system setup is path independent and user can use installation path of his choice in his PC.

Only con side I can see of this method is, that each Lauterbach user need to have the same Environment variable `Project_BuildSupport` defined in all the systems used in a team.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the line starting with `SYS=`.

TRACE32 will usually find its system directory automatically based on the location of the started executable.

(And when you remove the line starting with `TMP=` TRACE32 will use the default temporary directory for the user.)

Comment: So this configuration file will work on other user's pc too after removing line SYS ?